# Transformar uma imagem em um button submit HTML5/CSS3

Tags: html5, css3

Eu gostaria de transformar uma imagem em um botão, porém mantendo a propriedade submit (de enviar formulário nela) é possível?
O código abaixo demonstra o que eu queria fazer:

```html
<form method="post" action={{route('relatorio.Pessoa')}}>
   <input type="image" src="https://icons-for-free.com/iconfiles/png/512/32px+Free+Set+Download-1320568210130207016.png" title="Gerar relatório pdf" style="max-widht:32px; max-height:32px;">
   <input type="submit" src="https://icons-for-free.com/iconfiles/png/512/32px+Free+Set+Download-1320568210130207016.png" title="Gerar relatório pdf">
</form>
```

No primeiro input é uma imagem que eu queria, mas não consigo submeter o formulário.
No segundo input eu submeto o formulário, mas a imagem não aparece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara basicamente use um `<button>` com `type=submit` (que já é o valor *default* na verdade) com uma `<img>` dentro.

Veja essa documentação: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type

> **O possíveis valores são:**
> **submit:** O botão envia os dados do formulário para o servidor. Esse é o padrão se o atributo não for especificado, ou se o atributo é dinamicamente mudado para um valor vazio ou inválido.

Sobre o nome do botão, para deixar mais acessível vc pode usar o atributo `aria-label="Gerar relatório pdf"`, assim quando ele receber o focus de um leitor de tela o usuário saberá do que se trata. Aqui tem um exemplo na documentação oficial da Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-label_attribute#Exemplo_1_V%C3%A1rias_Etiquetas

Adicionei apenas um pequeno CSS para limpar os estilos padrão do `user-agent`, assim vc pode customizar a imagem como quiser mais livremente

```css
button {
  all: unset;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: revert;
}
```

```html
<form>

  <button type="submit" aria-label="Gerar relatório pdf">
    <img src="https://icons-for-free.com/iconfiles/png/512/32px+Free+Set+Download-1320568210130207016.png"  style="max-widht:32px; max-height:32px;">
  </button>
    
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ao utilizar o *type* `image` da seguinte forma, já será por padrão `submit`:

```
<input type="image" src="/image.png" border="0" alt="Submit"/>
```

Código completo em HTML:

```html
<form method="post" action={{route('relatorio.Pessoa')}}>
   <input type="image" src="https://icons-for-free.com/iconfiles/png/512/32px+Free+Set+Download-1320568210130207016.png" title="Gerar relatório pdf" alt="Submit" style="max-widht:32px; max-height:32px;">
</form>
```